# Linux delete files at least 2 weeks old AND (day of month) % 14 != 0

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, delete-file

I'm creating backup of my database every day.

For hard disk saving how can I delete files older than `2 weeks` AND `(day of month) % 14 != 0` from *shell script*?

So I'm looking for command like `find / -mtime +14 -exec rm {} \;`, with addition of *not deleteting* files created in 14'th or 28'th day of any month.

I'd like to have daily backups for **last 2 weeks** and **once every 2 weeks**(almost) **afterwards**?

PHP code in loop would be:

```
$mtime = filemtime($file); // Last modified date of file (created)
$day_mtime = date('j', $mtime); // Day of month (1-31)
$two_weeks_ago = time() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 14;

if ($mtime < $two_weeks_ago && $day_mtime % 14 != 0) {
    // Delete file older than 2 weeks 
    // AND not modified not 14'th nor 28'th day of month
}
```

Comment: Why get complicated. Start by looking for anything created on the 14th or 28th and copy it out of the way to a 2 week and a 4 week archive respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the bash equivalent. A couple of point to note when moving from php to bash:

- In bash `$` means "the value of..." so `mtime` is the variable and `$mtime` is the value of the variable
- The notation `$(...)` means run the command in the parenthesis and capture with its output
  So, `$(stat -c %Y $file)` is replaced with the output of `stat -c %Y $file`
- There can be no spaces around the assignment operators `a=b` works, `a = b` does not

  ```
  mtime=$(stat -c %Y $file)
  day_mtime=$(date -d@$mtime +%d)
  two_weeks_ago=$(date -d '2 weeks ago' +%s)
  mod_14_day=$(expr $day_mtime 14)
  if [ $mtime -lt $two_weeks_ago ] && [ $mod_14_day -eq 0 ] ; then
  fi
  ```

Comment: Okay, acutally i wast looking for writing that php code to bash.
I was looking form a command like `find / -mtime +14 -exec rm {} \;`, but with addition `(week of day) % 14 != 0`

Comment: Yeah, the % 14 is such a special case you won't find anything that will do that out of the box on Linux (or probably any other platform). You can use the `find` to feed the above script to reduce the list of candidate files, but the % 14 will have to be done with custom code.

Comment: That / in find is kinda dangerous to post